# Jasmine and Angularjs error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to do a simple test on a AngularJS $scope. I've followed multiple tutorials but keep getting an error. The error that keeps showing is:

"*Module 'onePortal' is not available! You either messpelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.*

My Controller Code looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('onePortal', []);

app.controller('indexController', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'Hello World!';
});
```

My Test Code looks like:

```
    'use strict';

    describe('indexController', function() {
      var scope;

      beforeEach(angular.mock.module('onePortal'));
      beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('indexController', {$scope: scope});
      }));

      it('should have variable test = "Hello World!"', function() {
        expect(scope.text).toBe('Hello World!');
      });
   });
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you are including the script containing the app declaration in your jasmine test html?

Comment: I've referenced the script file to be tested in the karma config file if that is what you meant.

Comment: Can you share the Karma config file? I got it working in a fiddle by copy-pasting, note the order of script dependencies there - http://jsfiddle.net/eitanp461/L7bQf/

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the fact that I'm using codeigniter also. Because I done what you did "Eitan Peer" and it worked. But when I placed karma back inside the codeigniter directory, I wasn't getting anywhere.